# Unity missing PostProcessing namespace in VS Code

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access and change the bloom properties in Postprocessing component via script but I can't seem to find the namespace for UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing.
I have installed the PostProcessing package (v3.1.1) via unity package manager but still there are no PostProcessing namespace can someone help me with this ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing Universal Render Pipeline as well? Maybe it can help... not sure though.

Comment: I already installed universal render pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a way around this issue. To anyone who still have issue and come to this post all you need to do is add

```
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;
```

After you have install the univiersal render pipline and post processing package.Then you can access the bloom setting via the volume profile using

```
Bloom tempBloom = null;
volume.profile.TryGet<Bloom>(out tempBloom);
// anycode you want to add after
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions:**

Try removing VS Code package from package manager and reimport it and then restart project and VS Code, it should work.

Note: some times VS Code takes time to or doesn't even recognize newly imported packages because of some VS Code extensions issue thats why people prefer using full IDEs like Rider or VS Community.

if you are using URP try declaring namespace:

```
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal
```

Hopefully it will help... happy coding :)

Comment: Still doesn't work sadly and I tried to swtich to VS community IDE but still the namespace can't be found

Comment: updated my answer, actually i just found out that unity has changed rendering namespace for each type of render pipelines, hopefully now it will work.

Comment: Thanks for updating but I already found a way around the problem